# Checkstyle - Method with annotation must be before constructor

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle

How can I define a [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) validation to make sure that *all the methods with a specific annotation* appear before the constructor of a java class?

The following should be accepted by the validation:

```java
class User {

    @Injected // -> [OK]: method with @Injected is before the constructor. 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The following should be causing a Checkstyle violation:

```java
class User {
    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Injected // -> [NOK]: method should be before the constructor
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there a [Checkstyle Check available out of the box](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks.html) that could be configured to check this or a [custom Check implemenation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/writingchecks.html) is needed to implement this?

Comment: Maybe it is only an unwritten rule but I think, the sequence of methods in the source doesn't guarantee anything about the functionality or even the bytecode produced. Therefore, why should any tool for static analysis do care?

Comment: Checkstyle can help to keep the code tidy and force developers to put specific elements where they "belong". For example the "InnerTypeLast" check, which is supported of out the box, forces the developers to declare nested (inner) classes/interfaces at the bottom of the class after all method and field declarations.

Comment: I am not aware of any valid reason for this message. The order of elements in a Java source file only matters from the point of view of compilation and initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such Checkstyle Check available out of the box.

One needs to implement a custom Checkstyle Check for this purpose and this custom validation must be triggered by adding it in the validation configuration xml.